# Android Studio 3.1: Under Tools menu, Android tool submenu is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I just upgrade Android Studio from 2.2 to  3.1. I am unable to find Gradle console and DDMS. Under Tools menu, there is no Android submenu that allow me to  get DDMS

I tried solutions that I can find online in stackoverflow

1) File => settings => Menus and Toolbars =>Main menu=>Tools => Android.
   I find under *Android*, there shows --------, no DDMS tool is listed, and 
   also the Apply button is grayed.

2) Help=> Find Action then type android for search. the screen display android 
   menu, under it  displays AVD manager and SDK manager only.

Anyone gets same problem? anyone find the DDMS and Gradle console in version 3.1?

Answer (score 27):

> Under Tools menu, there is no Android submenu that allow me to get DDMS

They removed that menu. All supported tools are directly in the Tools menu. This is covered in [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#user_interface_and_user_experience_improvements).

> no DDMS tool is listed

DDMS is deprecated. Most of its functions are now in Android Studio itself. You can still run the Android Device Monitor outside of Android Studio via the `monitor` tool, but you cannot have it and Android Studio 3.1 open at the same time, it appears. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) for more.

> anyone find the DDMS and Gradle console in version 3.1?

They removed the Gradle Console. There is the Build tool. By default, it gives you a tree version of the Gradle output. However, the second toolbar button down from the top, on the tool strip inside the Build tool, switches you from the tree view to raw Gradle output.

So, here is the Build tool in its default mode:

[image: Android Studio 3.1 Build Tool, Default Mode]

And here is the Build tool after toggling the toolbar button that I point to via the red arrow:

[image: Android Studio 3.1 Build Tool, Raw Gradle Output Mode]

Comment: Yes this is right Android Device Monitor is Not available in Android Studio 3.1 but **Device File Explorer** is work like a Android Device Monitor See i'll past my answer Hear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574127/how-to-open-android-device-monitor-in-latest-android-studio-3-1/49574244#49574244

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) DDMS is now deprecated. So you can use a new Android Profiler tool instead