# Where is the gradle console in Android Studio 3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my IDE to 3.1 from 3.0 and the gradle console is no longer available in the lower right hand corner of the app.  Where did you relocate this to, IntelliJ and Google?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545870/115145